# EasyAdmin3: method_exists(): Argument #1 ($object_or_class) must be of type object|string, array given

Tags: symfony5, easyadmin3

I've stumbled upon this error after trying to add  `configureFields` to my CRUD controller, because the stock configuration left behind the some fields out of my User table.

I've followed the documentation, having extra care to match the fields except the one relation I have (One to One with Unit table). If i throw it as TextField, throws me an error of not being able to change said to to string, when I throw is as TextField, gives me this error instead.

Is there any documentation that I'm missing?

I'm not sure if it worth to mention, but I'm using Symfony 5 as framework.